# Help interpreting gdb: segfault in function

Tags: c, gdb, segmentation-fault

I am trying to debug a segfault, and I have this output from gdb:

```
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048af9 in parse_option_list (ptr=0x6f72505f <Address 0x6f72505f out of bounds>, box_name=0x696d6978 <Address 0x696d6978 out of bounds>, option_list=0x313a7974, 
    num_elements=0x33313532) at submit.c:125
125                         memcpy(&(option_list[(*num_elements)].value), value, 24);
(gdb) p num_elements
$15 = (int *) 0x33313532
(gdb) p *num_elements
Cannot access memory at address 0x33313532
(gdb)
```

It looks to me like something in memcpy() is going haywire. But I can't figure out what exactly the problem is, since that line references so many variables.

Can somebody help figure out what the `0x8048af9 in parse_option_list...` line is telling me?

My function signature is:

```
int parse_option_list(char *ptr, char *box_name,
   struct option_list_values *option_list, int *num_elements)
```

And this might be useful:

```
struct option_list_values {
    char value[24];
    char name[24];
};
```

Also, the variables `value` and `name` are not segfaulting (but if you think they are, i can post the code which sets those values.) But right now, if I can understand this gdb output, I will be happy as a clam! Thank you!

Comment: I'd guess that 0x8048af9 is just the address of the faulting instruction (which gdb was able to find existing within the parse_option_list function).  Was this binary built with optimizations?  It might be easier to debug an unoptimized version.

Comment: Optimizations are disabled. (by default. I just added -O0 to be sure. same problem.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have all the signs of a classic buffer overflow.  The values of all the stack parameters have been overwritten by ASCII text - here is the translation of those values (assuming you have a little-endian architecture, which looks right):

```
ptr = 0x6f72505f = "_Pro"
box_name = 0x696d6978 = "ximi"
option_list = 0x313a7974 = "ty:1"
num_elements = 0x33313532 = "2513"
```

Concatenating them together gives `"_Proximity:12513"` - if this substring looks familiar to you, you should be able to track down where that data is being copied around - somewhere you are copying it into an array stored on the stack, without proper bounds checking.

Comment: ah. i hadn't thought about endianness (silly intel). and that substring is indeed familiar - what a good technique for using gdb. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

0x8048af9 is the instruction pointer - the address of the executable code in memory that your code was at when the SEGFAULT occurred.

Are you sure that option_list[(*num_elements)].value is a valid address? You might have a buffer overflow, and be overwriting something you shouldn't be.

If num_elements is the length of option_list, then option_list[(*num_elements)] refers to just after the end of the list.

Comment: The "address" 0x33313532 does look quite suspiciously like it's full of ascii characters (ie. "3152"). I second a1kmm's suggestion of buffer overflow.

Comment: not quite sure that is it. (I mean, its probably a buffer overflow but) nowhere in my data stream does that sequence of ascii characters exist. and its different each time (with more characters which are not present in that sequence)

Comment: ah. you were right! I was just getting confused by endian-ness when looking at the hex value.

Answer (score 0):

ptr=0x6f72505f - Address 0x6f72505f out of bounds
This is the useful part in this case
The first input to parse_option_list is invalid. Possibly an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Perhaps - though I can printf() that guy just fine. It seems to be null-terminated (since printf doesn't segfault) and it contains valid/expected data.